# What is the . symbol in matlab, how to change it to python

Tags: python, matlab

```
Xnorm = (X-repmat(mu,m,1))./repmat(sigma,m,1);
```

what does the . here do? And if I want to change it to the python, what should I do?

Comment: IIRC, `./` means to do element-wise division instead of matrix division.  As for how to change it to python ... that depends entirely on what libraries, etc. you're using.  e.g. `numpy` does elementwise division by default if you're using arrays ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB you would explicitly replicate elements with that `repmat` and then do elementwise division with `./` as also stated in the comments. You could have also used [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for under-the-hood replication aka `broadcasting` prior to `2016B` and division in one go, like so -

```
bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,X,mu),sigma)
```

In this post I am assuming that you are working with NumPy arrays in Python. In NumPy, the [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is done implicitly. MATLAB would have the same starting from `2016b`. So, we can simply skip the `repmat` part. Thus, if the input arrays are floating pt ones, you can simply do -

```
(X-mu)/sigma
```

If working with int arrays, I could suggest two ways to achieve the desired output.

One way would be with [`np.true_divide`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.true_divide.html) -

```
np.true_divide((X-mu),sigma)
```

Another way would be to convert one of the arrays to floating pt, so that the desired output would be upcasted, like so -

```
(X-mu)/(sigma).astype(float)
```

**Sample runs**

1) MATLAB :

```
X =
     1     5     9    13    17
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     7    11    15    19
     4     8    12    16    20
mu =
   101   102   103   104   105
sigma =
   201   202   203   204   205
m =
     4
out =
     -0.49751      -0.4802     -0.46305     -0.44608     -0.42927
     -0.49254     -0.47525     -0.45813     -0.44118     -0.42439
     -0.48756      -0.4703      -0.4532     -0.43627     -0.41951
     -0.48259     -0.46535     -0.44828     -0.43137     -0.41463
```

2) NumPy :

```
In [37]: X
Out[37]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 14, 18],
       [ 3,  7, 11, 15, 19],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16, 20]])

In [38]: mu
Out[38]: array([101, 102, 103, 104, 105])

In [39]: sigma
Out[39]: array([201, 202, 203, 204, 205])

In [40]: np.true_divide(X-mu,sigma)
Out[40]: 
array([[-0.49751244, -0.48019802, -0.46305419, -0.44607843, -0.42926829],
       [-0.49253731, -0.47524752, -0.45812808, -0.44117647, -0.42439024],
       [-0.48756219, -0.47029703, -0.45320197, -0.43627451, -0.4195122 ],
       [-0.48258706, -0.46534653, -0.44827586, -0.43137255, -0.41463415]])
```

Answer (score 0):

IN MATLAB it's called [`rdivide` - right array element-wise division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html).

```
>> [1,2;3,4]./[5,6;7,8]

ans =

    0.2000    0.3333
    0.4286    0.5000
```

Python equivalent is [`numpy.divide`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html#numpy-divide).

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) / np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
array([[ 0.2       ,  0.33333333],
       [ 0.42857143,  0.5       ]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It means element wise division
Matlab Example

http://in.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html;jsessionid=e4b080e387b57aaf3b1e526a26d9

Divide elementwise Python Equivalent

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html

Answer (score 0):

Element division instead of the default matrix division.